# three.js - Invert camera rotation matrix

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a scene with objects and a camera controlled by a trackball. When I add a new object to the root object, I want it in the orientation it would have had before the camera moved around. For example, if you don't rotate the camera, a torus will show up with the hole facing the screen, the ring in the x,y screen plane.

I tried to apply the inverse matrix of the camera, but that doesn't work.

```
var m = THREE.Matrix4()
m.getInverse(camera.matrixWorld)
obj.setRotationFromMatrix(m)
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simply to apply the camera rotation:
    obj.setRotationFromMatrix(camera.matrixWorld)

The object is then facing the camera.

Answer (score -1):

You need to declare the object as "new" as well reordering some of the wording. Try this:

```
var m = new THREE.Matrix4();
m.getInverse( camera.matrixWorld );
obj.rotation.setFromRotationMatrix(m);
```

Comment: On Recently versions, getInverse function was removed